# starting multiple camelcontext with one master context

Tags: apache-camel

What is the best way (and allowed) to start multiple other camelContext from a let's say Master CamelContext :

I try it this way:

```
    @ContextName("master")
    public class MasterContext extends CdiCamelContext {


        @PostConstruct
        void customize() {

            setName("MASTER-Context");
            //some config  for the master.. properties...

            for (Service service : services){
               CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext() ;

               ctx.addRoutes(getRouteBuilder(someinfo))
            }

        }
```

I couldn't find an example of one camelContext creating others...

and doing it this way it's looping and get recursively called....

Comment: What is the particular reason to do that?
CamelConext is on Application level.
If you need to split large CamelContext to smaller pieces there is a RouteContext and you can have many of them included and referenced in CamelContext.

Comment: Yes this is bad practice, use 1 CamelContext and N routes.

Comment: I wanted a kind of application that manages multiple services and each service would have it's own camel context. I would like to stop some routes without others (kind of grouping routes)and also each having it's own Properties

Comment: So, you are talking about routes level, not about context on application level. Maybe you can thing about Microservice conception instead? One WAR (application) per service, deployed separately at any level from one EAR for all and up to one container per service?

Comment: @Vadim, microservice conception is what i want to achieve, but i start it without j2ee container but standalone ( althought it could be deployed in a j2ee container) using cdi.Main that will start the main application context and an application can be composed of one or more service. the application could start with all service, then when scaling, services could be deployed elsewhere and be loadbalanced without compromising the whole app. it could also be easy to test and i start with camel, but I think all feature i need are there... will try to push some code on github and come back'later

Comment: some added info: now i don't have looping anymore... it was because i started the so called child contexts with the registry of the master context. now i would like to pass some config to each child context, but got some bugs configuring the properties component. will add more info on this next week

Comment: OK. Got it. I'm going right now with similar pattern, but with EAR/WAR instead of handling it on camel contexts level. One service -> One WAR then it can be One Service ->one EAR, but if needed EAR can have more than one WARs.Of course it will be not exact "microservice" conception, but for transition period from standard SOA it can be useful.

Comment: that's it, but not EAR/WAR first, but just a Main class wich starts services and services can later be "extracted" to live alone in it's own Main. So no J2ee server invloved, just Java se (and later perhaps use kubernetes to manage all these Main process).will share the link when I pushed my code

Answer (score 0):

You should try using an OSGi container like [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/download.html) or [RedHat JBoss Fuse](https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/overview/?referrer=jbd).
When you deploy an application in such containers, it gets its own CamelContext.

Communication between CamelContexts can be performed using [vm components](https://camel.apache.org/vm.html) or queues using [jms](https://camel.apache.org/jms.html) or [ActiveMQ](https://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) components.
CamelContexts creation is managed by the container. The container also lets you start and stop single routes in any Context, or you can control them in your application with [ControlBus](https://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html).

Comment: thx for the answer, but i am trying to do this without any container, just a s andalone java se app...

Answer (score -3):

I am working in insurance domain where selling insurance to individual, group  i.e. company and claim etc are considered as separate product.But all these module may be part of single product where single camelContext works fine.If I have to deploy all these module as separate war/Jar then refactoring of routes became nightmare because after refactoring I need to make sure everything works fine business wise. So my need was to deploy each module if required. To achieve this I tried to create routeContext but routeContext has their own limitation so I created separate camelContext for each module and to do so you need to refer correct camelContext at the time of creating endpoint, proxy etc otherwise you will have many issue at runtime.Example :-

```
 <camel:proxy id="abc" camelContextId="camelContext-main" serviceInterface="com.abc" serviceUrl="direct:abc"/>
<camel:endpoint id="xyz" camelContextId="camelContext-second" uri="bean:klm"></camel:endpoint>
<camel:endpoint id="123" camelContextId="camelContext-main" uri="bean:dddd"></camel:endpoint>
<camel:endpoint id="ssss" camelContextId="camelContext-second" uri="bean:ttt"></camel:endpoint>
```

If you have multiple camelContext then spring will bind all the routes successfully with first camelContext, when spring container will start binding next camelContext routes then it will start throwing exception.
So from second camelContext, endpoints must have correct reference to context because at this point spring container got two camelContext reference and got confused to which user want to bind the route. Hence if you will specify correct camel context id at endpoints then no issue. Everything will work fine.Thanks